# Have a table border , but no cell borders

Tags: itext, pdf-generation, border

I want to render tables which have a border outside them, but none inside.

I know I can use `PDFPCell.setBorder` to disable borders of all cells inside table, but I want a border outside the whole table as well. Any way in iText to do so? I don't see any such method in the API.

Adding to directContent might be possible, but it would create issues when table stretches against pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be achieved by adding this table as a cell to a new table with single cell.